# ContinueConversationAsync() requires users to chat first after publishing bot

Tags: c#, botframework

After publishing the bot, the user needs to chat with the bot again first in order send a proactive message. I followed [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) but instead of storing the conversation reference in the variable, I stored it in cosmosDB. However I still can't send proactive message if the user has not chatted with the bot after publishing. Is there a way to send proactive message even when the user has not chatted with the bot after publishing?

DialogBot

```
    private async void AddConversationReference(ITurnContext turnContext)
    {
        var userstate = await _userProfileAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new BasicUserState());
        userstate.SavedConversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();

        _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(userstate.SavedConversationReference.User.Id, userstate.SavedConversationReference, (key, newValue) => userstate.SavedConversationReference);
    }

    protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        AddConversationReference(turnContext);

        return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }


    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

        AddConversationReference(turnContext);

        await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
    }
```

api/notify

```
    namespace SabikoBotV2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/notify")]

    public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
        private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<BasicUserState> _userProfileAccessor;

        public NotifyController(UserState userState, IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, ICredentialProvider credentials, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
        {
            _userProfileAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<BasicUserState>("UserProfile");

            _adapter = adapter;
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
            _appId = ((SimpleCredentialProvider)credentials).AppId;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
            {
                _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
                {
                    await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
                }

                return new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
                    ContentType = "text/html",
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userstate = await _userProfileAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new BasicUserState(), cancellationToken);

            if (userstate.SavedConversationReference.ServiceUrl != null && userstate.SavedConversationReference.ServiceUrl != string.Empty)
            {
        MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(userstate.SavedConversationReference.ServiceUrl);
            }
            else if (turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl != null && turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl != string.Empty)
            {
                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);            
            }
            else
            {
                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("https://facebook.botframework.com/");
            }

            if(userstate.Reminders != null)
            {
                foreach (var reminder in userstate.Reminders)
                {            
                    if (reminder.DateAndTime.TrimMilliseconds() == DateTimeNowInGmt().TrimMilliseconds())
                    {                     
                        var timeProperty = new TimexProperty(reminder.DateAndTimeTimex);
                        var naturalDate = timeProperty.ToNaturalLanguage(DateTimeNowInGmt().TrimMilliseconds());
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"It's {DateTimeNowInGmt().ToLongDateString()}. \n\nReminding you to {reminder.Subject}.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static DateTime DateTimeNowInGmt()
        {
            TimeZoneInfo phTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Taipei Standard Time");
            var t = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime phTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(t, phTimeZone);

            return phTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could provide more details about where the bot is hosted or running prior to publishing and what errors you are getting, it would be helpful. Also, once the bot is published, it "forgets" it was okay to talk to different users. You might need to add [TrustServiceUrl](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/proactiveTrustUrls/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) to get it working.

Comment: The bot is hosted on azure bot service. I updated my question and added codes in api/notify can you try and check it. i tried that trustServiceUrl but it does not work.

Comment: Your implementation seems to be a bit complicated. All you have to do is: 1.Store the _conversationReferences in Cosmos or Blob (so it can persist between bot reloads).
2.Before sending the proactive message, trust the service url from the conversation reference.

Comment: Also,you have to ensure that you are sending the right serviceURL as you are using a 3-way if statement, you will need to verify which is getting hit when the user wants to send a proactive message on Facebook. One more thing is, you are most likely trying to pull from userState but that may not exist for a newly-deployed bot and you should make sure that it is not empty. If your _conversation Reference is stored in the memory,there won't be any conversationReferences to proactively message.